# every real number has exactly one integer part

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I am self studying book [Analysis I by Tao](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8185931623), there is an exercise on proving:

Exercise 5.4.3:

for every real number x, there is exactly one integer N such that $$N \leq x \lt N+1$$

Can anyone give some hints for me to continue my thinking on the proof?

Comment: suppose there's more than one...

Comment: If $n\leq m$, then either $n=m$ or $n+1\leq m$

Comment: Since this is a fundamental property, it's difficult to answer without knowing how exactly real numbers are defined, and which theorems you have already proven. To help finding an appropriate answer, can you tell us how real numbers are defined in the book? Dedekind cuts? Equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences? Axioms?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that there's at least two integers such that the property holds, and suppose that $M<N$.

Now, $M<N \le x <M+1<N+1$ according to the property, but we have that $M<N<M+1$ , but clearly because they're integers (is there an integer $N$ such that there is integers $M$ and $M+1$ and $M<N<M+1$ holds) , $M=N$ should also hold and we have a contradiction.

Comment: Strictly speaking we cannot deduce $M=N$ from $M<N<M+1$. But we can  imediately say that this is a contradiction.

Comment: I agree with @gebruiker because you said $M < N$ holds.  If this is true, then we can't have $M = N$.

Comment: This issue could also be corrected by replacing the assumption $M<N$ with the assumption $M\leq N$. Then we have no contradiction, just a straight implication that $M\leq N<M+1$ implies $M=N$.

Comment: I edited the proof by contradiction to imply both $M<N$ and $M=N$. As gebruiker said, $M < N < M+1$ is a contradiction. However, of course proving that if there is $M$ and $N$ so that the property holds with the assumption that $M\le N$, $M=N$ as ptrsinclair showed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I am still not sure about the existence of such a $$N \leq x < N+1$$. I know that there exist integers $$N_1, N_2$$ such that $$N_1 \leq x \lt N_2$$.  However, $$N_2 = N_1 + 1$$ is a stronger statement. I think I should also prove the existence part and include your uniqueness part to have a complete proof. Am I right?

Comment: @user2262504: You are exactly right. You need to also prove existence which, it seems, Eemil's and Singh's answers do not do.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be $N_1,N_2,\dots N_n$ such that $N_n\le x < N_n+1$, $n\in \{1,2,3,\dots \}$

For simplicity let us that $N_1$ and $N_2$ for a while  and then we will generalize for all $n\in \{1,2,3,\dots \}$.

**So let us assume that  $N_1\le x < N_1+1$ and $N_2\le x < N_2+1$**

**Case I**

Let $x$ be an integer

then $N_1=x$ and $N_2=x \implies N_1=x=N_2 \implies N_1=N_2$

$\therefore$ for all $n\in \{1,2,3,\dots \}$ $N_1=N_2=N_3=\dots =N_n$

Therefore we have unique integer.

**Case II**

Let $x$ be a non-integer real number.

Since we have $N_1\le x < N_1+1$

therefore we can write $x=N_1+0.def\dots$ **where $d,e,f$ are individual digits**.

Similarly we have $x=N_2+0.abx\dots$ **where $a,b,c$ are individual digits**.

**Without loss of generality we can assume that $N_1 > N_2$**

Therefore $N_1=N_2+m$ where $m\in \mathbb{N}$

$\therefore x=N_1+0.def\dots = N_2+m+0.xyz\dots=N_2+m.xyz\dots$

$\therefore x>N_2+1$ and so we have a contradiction.

Therefore we have unique $N$ that satisfies the inequality.

Case-by-case analysis completes our proof.

**Note**

> "$\dots $" in $"0.abc\dots $" means that there may be any number of digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness is easy.

To prove existence, use the Archimedean property to show that there is some integer $M$ which is smaller than x, and an integer larger than x. Show that the set of integers which are at least $M$ and at most $x$ is finite, and use the maximum value of this set.